# code is Not returning the correct character in cpp

Tags: c++, string, char, return

**Question:** First uppercase letter in a string ( Recursive)
**Doubt:** why this code is not returning the correct character even though it is entering in the if clause at correct time(when the letter is in uppercase). I have added these cout statements  for debuging purpose only.

```
# include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
char UpperCase(string str, int i){
    
    cout<<" str "<<i<<" "<<str[i]<<endl;
    if(i==str.length()){
        return '0';
    }
    if(str[i]>=65 && str[i]<=90 ){
        char r=str[i];
        cout<<" r "<<i<<" "<<r<<endl;
        return r;
    }
    
    UpperCase(str, i+1);
}
int main(){
string str;
char r;
cout<<"Enter string : ";
cin>>str;
 r=UpperCase(str,0);
 cout<<r<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
Enter no of element : geeksforgeeKs
 str 0 g
 str 1 e
 str 2 e
 str 3 k
 str 4 s
 str 5 f
 str 6 o
 str 7 r
 str 8 g
 str 9 e
 str 10 e
 str 11 K
 r 11 K
ö
```

**Expected**

```
K (instead of ö)
```

Comment: Most relevant to your question, what does it *return* in *all* reachable code paths (looking at *you*, unreaped return result from the recursed `UpperCase` call). [Turn up your compiler warnings and treat them as errors](https://godbolt.org/z/qvboajjT1).

Comment: Why have you chosen a recursive approach? A loop would be simpler and not gobble stack.

Comment: @lurker yes! it is easy from loops but  Actually I am learning recursion.

Comment: As was pointed out in the answer, it's best not to use "magic numbers". There is a standard macro which you can use to check for upper case: use [`isupper(str[i])`](https://www.cprogramming.com/fod/isupper.html) instead of `str[i]>=65 && str[i]<=90`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is an academic exercise. *No one* would actually implement this task using recursion (nor would they use magic numbers, [the plague known as `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h), a *dreadful* practice common on junk "competitive" programming sites, etc.)

That said, a *very* common mistake made by students when learning recursion is failing to realize that function conveying their results by return-value need to be reaped from the recursed call. You've fallen victim to that mistake here.

Stripping the debugging statements and just looking at the code itself:

```
char UpperCase(string str, int i)
{
    if (i == str.length())
    {
        return '0';
    }
    if (str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 90)
    {
        return str[i];
    }

    UpperCase(str, i + 1); // <===== HERE
}
```

Note that `UpperCase` returns a `char` (or at least it claims to). But in the recursed case you're not reaping that result. In fact, you're not returning *anything* . This is not only a logical bug, it also leads to *undefined behavior*. Anyone that invokes this function to reap its result and does *not* fall into one of the other two targeted exit conditions *immediately* will have no specified result. Your compiler will tell you this if you pay attention to its warnings:

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

The simplest way to address this is to remember what your function is supposed to return, and then make sure it returns it.

```
char UpperCase(string str, int i)
{
    if (i == str.length())
    {
        return '0';
    }
    if (str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 90)
    {
        return str[i];
    }

    return UpperCase(str, i + 1); // <===== FIXED
}
```